# how to interact with eth contract

Tags: myetherwallet

I would like to interact with the old Etherflyer contract 0x1ce7ae555139c5ef5a57cc8d814a867ee6ee33d8 to check the tokens I had with them but myetherwallet asks me ABI / JSON. How can I recover this data? Is possible?
I thank those who want to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuo need to compile your contract to get the abi.
Usualy when someone want to give permission to someone to interact with their smart contract they give users the abi and the contract addressso they can interact with the SC.

However you can just use thei site and just use theyr Dapp to interact with theyr smart contract .